# Running standalone window manager without a D-Bus session in Linux

Tags: linux, window-manager, dbus

Here is a prehistory for my question, if some more details are needed, the actual question is in the second paragraph.

So I have been using standalone window manager for a couple of months on different Linux distributions, and to launch the WM i just put `exec awesome` into the .xinitrc, so I didn't launch the dbus daemon. On systemd-systems, like Debian, I have noticed that the D-Bus user session starts up automatically whenever I run AwesomeWM. The same happened when I was using Void Linux with runit init system. Now I am running Emacs as a window manager on Artix Linux, which also does not use systemd, with this line in my .xinitrc `exec emacs`, and it works perfectly well. But the dbus daemon is not launched for Emacs, so all the application that are running inside do not use the DBus. I suspect it is not OK.

When using a standalone window manager without a D-Bus session daemon does it mean that some functionality of my applications may not be available? Or if my WM works fine without a D-Bus daemon does it mean that applications that I am using do not use D-Bus? Then what will happen if some application will need the D-Bus session? Or maybe my applications are connecting to the system wide D-Bus daemon if the session-local D-Bus daemon is not available? How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many programs either don't use D-Bus at all, or don't use the *session* bus (e.g. they might only need to talk to services on the system bus), or have fallbacks in case the session bus is unavailable. For example, a mail app may only need the session bus to send popup notifications (displayed by awesomewm's `naughty` module) and nothing else, so even if the bus is unavailable 99% of the app's functionality still remains.

(The session and system buses are not interchangeable – they have different purposes and different policies. There's only one system bus per system, but one session bus per UID (or traditionally per X11 display); the system bus only allows privileged processes to 'host' a service while the session bus grants all privileges to whatever UID it's running as.)

However, libdbus (the most commonly used D-Bus client library) has an *[autolaunch](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html#automatic_launching)* mechanism where it will automatically spawn a `dbus-daemon --session` if none is available yet. As long as this feature hasn't been disabled by your distribution, the first program that needs a session bus will cause one to be auto-started and its socket address stored in `~/.dbus/` for other programs to find.

Autolaunch isn't great, for the same reason that "sudo /etc/init.d/foo start" isn't – sometimes unwanted environment that was supposed to only affect one specific app may leak into the auto-spawned daemon, and from it into all bus-spawned services. So in systemd-based distributions the "user session" bus is started as a user service (which happens at login time, long before the WM starts), and in other distributions it's generally recommended to start it explicitly from your xinitrc.

(With more and more apps using the session bus for various purposes, I would suggest starting it even if nothing in your setup needs a session bus *yet*. The daemon only uses resources when it's actually forwarding messages, so it does not hurt to have it idle in background.)

If there's exactly one thing being started in your xinitrc, it's easiest to wrap it in `dbus-run-session`:

```
exec dbus-run-session awesomewm
```

For more elaborate xinitrc scripts, either wrap the *entire* script:

```
if [ ! "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ]; then
    exec dbus-run-session -- "$0" "$@"
fi
xbindkeys &
exec emacs
```

or start the bus inline using `dbus-launch`:

```
if [ ! "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ]; then
    eval "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-x11)"
fi
```